# React Framer Motion how to stop and play animation

Tags: reactjs, animation, framer-motion

Please help me making out how can I stop and play framer motion animation. Or any other lib like GSAP or Lottie which can be used with ReactJS. The thing is that I need to add animated elements over a video. And the video can be stopped/played like any other video. And the animations also need to be stopped/played. I can't use FFmpeg as I only need to mock these, not produce an actual animated video. Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In Framer Motion you can use Animation Controls to stop and start animations.

From [the docs](https://www.framer.com/docs/animation/#component-animation-controls):

> The `useAnimation` hook can be used to create a set of imperative
> [`AnimationControls`](https://www.framer.com/api/utilities/#animationcontrols) with a `start` and `stop` method. These controls can be
> passed to one or more motion components via the `animate` prop.